# xUnit false positive when comparing null terminated strings

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I've come across odd behavior when comparing strings. First assert passes, but I don't think it should.. Second assert fails, as expected...

```
[Fact]
public void StringTest()
{
    string testString_1 = "My name is Erl. I am a program\0";
    string testString_2 = "My name is Erl. I am a program";

    Assert.Equal<string>(testString_1, testString_2);
    Assert.True(testString_1.Equals(testString_2));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `String.Compare(testString_1, testString_2)`?

Comment: Looks like I've stumbled upon known (and already reported) bug: http://xunit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=9649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed.

Here: [Assert.Equal("foo", "foo\0") does not fail](http://xunit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=9649)